# .htaccess 301 redirect keeping question mark and variable in the redirected URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi everyone and thank you for your time.

So I've searched around for a line in .htaccess I can use that will work to redirect a URL like:

product-category/serpentine-pulley-kit/volvo-penta/?orderby=popularity

to mydomain.com/wheretopurchase/

When I do do this though, it adds the ?orderby=popularity to the end of the new URL like

mydomain.com/wheretopurchase/?orderby=popularity

Can someone help me get that last part of the url out of there and just redirect cleanly?

Thank you again everyone for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Add a single `?` onto the end of the rewrite and that will truncate the query string

Comment: Redirect 301 /product-category/pulleykits/?orderby=popularity http://www.example.com/products/ didn't even redirect anymore, and doing as you said like Redirect 301 /product-category/pulleykits/?orderby=popularity http://www.example.com/products/? didn't work either with or without the last forward slash. :(

Comment: I didn't realise you were using `Redirect`, I assumed you were using a `RewriteRule`. This highlights the importance of including as much info as you can in the question. Simply describing the behaviour you've implemented isn't really enough without showing *how* you've done it. So I'd suggest adding the relevant parts of your `.htaccess` to the question.

Comment: My apologies arco - you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^product-category/serpentine-pulley-kit/volvo-penta/?$ http://example.com/wheretopurchase/? [R=302,L]
```

If `?orderby=popularity` is important for the test, you can add (before RewriteRule)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^orderby=popularity$
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

Comment: This did not work, but thank you for trying. it still generated a 404, this is what I added: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^orderby=popularity$
RewriteRule ^product-category/serpentine-pulley-kit/volvo-penta/?$ http://www.example.com/products/? [R=301,L]

Comment: It's an external rewrite, you see `http://example.com/wheretopurchase/` in your browser ? If you use 301, you have to test from other browser, to avoid cache problem...